# The square of any odd number is $1$ more than a multiple of $8$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm taking a single variable calculus course and asked following :

Say wether the following is a valid proof or not :

> the square of any odd number is 1 more than a multiple of $8$.

Proof : By the division theorem any number can be expressed in one of the forms $4q , 4q+1 , 4q+2 , 4q+3$

Squaring each of these gives :

$$(4q+1)^2=16q^2+8q+1=8(2q^2+q)+1$$

$$(4q+3)^2=16q^2+24q+9=8(2q^2+3q+1)+1$$

My answer :

I think this proof is invalid as it does not prove ' the square of any odd number is $1$ more than a multiple of $8$. ' is true for any odd number as it does not prove for the odd number $(2n+1)$ or $(2n-1)$. Is my assertion correct ?

Comment: Why do you think that 4q, 4q+1, 4q+2, 4q+3 do not cover all natural numbers?

Comment: @miracle173 I think that is one of my points of confusion, 'all natural numbers' is not mentioned , just 'any number'.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is basically correct. What you have forgotten is that any odd number can be written as $4q+1$ or $4q+3$ (since the other alternatives according to the division theorem is even and therefore not equal to the odd number in question).

Another alternative is to square the number $2n+1$:

$$(2n+1)^2 = 4n^2+4n+1 = 4(n^2+n) +1 = 4(n+1)n + 1$$

And here either $n+1$ or $n$ is even so $(n+1)n$ is even so  $4(n+1)n$ is a multiple of $8$.

Yet another alternative is by induction. If $(2n+1)^2=8k+1$ you have that $(2(n+1)+1)^2= 4n^2+12n+9 = (2n+1)^2 + 8n+8 = 8(k+n+1) + 1$ and $(2(n-1)+1)^2 = 4n^2 -4n + 1 = (2n+1)^2 - 8n = 8(k-n) + 1$, and trivially it's true fore some integer $n$ so it's therefore true for all integers $n$.

Comment: your proof isn't different. To proof that n(n+1) is even you also have to represent n as 2k or 2k+1 and end up with the same representation of an odd number.

Comment: @miracle173 That depends on what you mean by different. To prove that $n(n+1)$ is even you can also use that at least one of $n$ and $n+1$ is even and use the fact that a product with an even number factor is even.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is valid and your comment isn't: the proof correctly states that an odd number can be represented as either $4q+1$ or $4q+3$ and argues, in both cases, that its square minus $1$ is divisible by $8$.

A different approach might be with congruences: an odd number is congruent modulo $8$ to $1$, $3$, $5$ or $7$; now
\begin{align}
1^2=1&\equiv 1\pmod{8}\\
3^2=9&\equiv 1\pmod{8}\\
5^2=25&\equiv 1\pmod{8}\\
7^2=49&\equiv 1\pmod{8}
\end{align}

Another approach. Let $n=2q+1$ be odd; then
$$
n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)=2q(2q+2)=4q(q+1)
$$
and $q(q+1)$ is even, so $4q(q+1)$ is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is valid.

(1) Since $2n-1=2(n-1)+1$, you don't have to consider $2n-1$ and $2n+1$ separately.

(2) Now consider only $2n+1$. We further divide it into two cases: (i) if $n$ is even, then $n=2q$ for some $q$ and so $2n+1=4q+1$. (ii) if $n$ is odd, then $n=2q+1$ for some $q$ and so $2n+1=4q+3$.

All possible cases are considered.